# Why std::begin uses trailing return type syntax?

Tags: c++, c++11, return, auto, decltype

The range-access function `std::begin` is declared as follows (for containers):

```
template< class C >
auto begin( C& c ) -> decltype(c.begin());
```

I just wonder why it's not simply

```
template< class C >
decltype(C::begin) begin( C& c );
```

Is there any difference between these two?

Comment: Did you _try_ it? If so, what happened? If not, why not?

Comment: The first version gets the type when `begin` is called. The second version gets the type of `begin`.

Comment: `C::begin` is (presumably) a member function, and `decltype(C::begin)` is something like `Iterator (C::*)()` (a pointer to member function), which differs from `Iterator`.

Comment: @Useless Yes, I did: https://wandbox.org/permlink/SpHJSCeSO1rbKJsQ and it worked.

Comment: @DanielLangr - Your test isn't correct. It calls `std::begin` on the vector via ADL. Try `*::begin()`, with scope resolution.

Comment: @StoryTeller Ooh, you're right, forgot about ADL. Still learning C++, thanks.

Comment: And your code is anyway relevant to the question. Otherwise it looks very much like you just posted an idle thought with no effort.

Comment: @DanielLangr You can prepend your custom `begin` with `::` or rename it to `my_begin` to avoid ADL, in this case your [example code won't compile](https://wandbox.org/permlink/6yfh10PkYVSGCilz).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The equivalent code would be

```
template< class C >
decltype(::std::declval<C &>().begin()) begin( C& c );
```

which is longer and potentially more error-prone.

Answer (score 3):

This version

```
template< class C >
decltype(C::begin) begin( C& c )
```

won't work, because

1. `decltype(C::begin)` means the type of the method, not the type of the result of the method call, and anyway
2. the `begin` method is overloaded for standard containers, and without the context of a function call (even if not evaluated), the compiler will be unable to decide which overload should participate

The `std::declval` version shown by VTT fixes that, by creating an un-evaluated function call context where the overload can be resolved. Using the trailing `decltype` instead saves repeating the argument type.